# Setting up Helvetica with fontconfig

Tags: fonts, fontconfig

I am running Xubuntu 12.04.

I installed Helvetica and Helvetica Neue. For some reason, websites that use Helvetica Neue display fine, but those who use Helvetica have some issues...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHkGk.png

With Helvetica Neue (yay tampermonkey!)...
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2c6mh.png

As you can see, there is a rather annoying problem: Helvetica is always **BOLD.**

When checking with `fc-match`

```
[CENSORED]@[CENSORED]:~$ fc-match Helvetica
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 9: reading configurations from ~/.fonts.conf is deprecated.
Helvetica-Bold.ttf: "Helvetica" "粗體"
```

That's why it displays funny! Helvetica matches to Helvetica-Bold.ttf, not Helvetica.ttf!

Is there anything I could add to ~/fonts.conf or something that could fix this issue? I don't like relying on Tampermonkey (yes, I wrote a script) to fix the display issues.